# Best data structure for closest range

Tags: data-structures, complexity-theory, computer-science, time-complexity, space-complexity

Consider i have set of ranges that an item can be in, and a given item, which data structure is considered fastest to provide the range that considered the closest to the item? I also care for space complexity so bring that into consideration.

a 1 dimensional example for the use case is frequency, consider we have frequency ranges and a frequency, we wish to find the closest frequency range to that frequency.

a 2 dimensional example is a game, consider we have a ball and objects on a plane, we divide objects to groups and want to find which of the groups is the closest to the ball.

Comment: Sorted array must be more than enough. Just do a binary search on the requested frequency. The closest frequency will be returned on Binary search.

Comment: maybe for 1 dimensional problem it is but what about 2 and 3 dimensions?

Comment: For 2 or higher dimensions, I'm thinking you are looking for an [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).